# How can I wait until the fragment was closed and then do something?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-fragments

I have a xamarin.android project, and I have the following classes:

In MyFragment.cs:

```
public class MyFragment : BaseAppCompactDialogFragment, IMyFragment
{
 ...
}
```

Then, I have an activity, something like (in MyActivity.cs):

```
public class MyActivity : BaseActivity
{
    private IMyFragment MyFragment;
    ...
    
 }
```

In MyActivity I have a method ActivityChanged which is attached as an event handler OnResume():

```
    private void ActivityChanged
    {
       ... 
    }
```

In the ActivityChanged method, how can I wait until MyFragment was closed and then do something?

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on how you are managing Fragment state you can leverage the OnHiddenChanged method:

public override void OnHiddenChanged(bool hidden){base.OnHiddenChanged(hidden);if (hidden){/*DO WORK*/}}

Comment: What does the ` fragment was closed` mean? The fragment has its own lifecycle and state.